# mouseover & mouseout fade effect stops when blog load more images

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, opacity, fade

i have a blog where i am using the fade effect on mouseover and mouseout changing image opacity. well, the problem is that my blog have infinite scroll and when it load more images, they doesn't appear with the effect :S

here is the jquery im using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#entry img.photo").on({
    mouseover: function() { $(this).fadeTo('slow', .5); },
    mouseout: function() { $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1); }
});
});
</script>
```

and there is a blog page where you can see it in 10 to 11 picture - [BLOG PAGE](http://somuchweeeed.tumblr.com/tagged/nsfw) - WARNING:CONTAINS ADULT CONTENT!

If anyone know how to solve this, tell please :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: remember to use `.stop()` so it does not keep fading after you mouse in and out the pic several times really fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseover', 'img.photo', function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', .5);
    });

    $(document).on('mouseout', 'img.photo', function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});
```